# Server listening to localhost:8080 can Apache still listen to port 80?

Tags: c++, linux, facebook, apache, port

I have a C++ server in linux using Mongoose listening on port 8080 for http requests. I'm using port 8080 because I have an Apache server already using port 80.

The reason I have my C++ server listening for http requests is so that I can receive the http GET sent by Facebook to get a user's Facebook info. For the Facebook server side Auth I'm redirecting to localhost:8080.

I am correctly getting the information sent from Facebook, but now Apache isn't serving up my html to the clients webpage (which works correctly if I only redirect to localhost).

Is it possible to make both of these work? Is the client still trying to get the index.html from port 80 or does it expect 8080 to now send this?

Comment: A web-client (browser or other client) by default always tries to get from port 80. It has to be explicitly told to fetch from some other port. If the client doesn't connect to the normal web-server, you probably has some problems with redirection.

Comment: That question could well have been placed as a follow-up [/edit] to your existing question, [C++ Linux Server getting Facebook HTTP Authentication message](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11946136/c-linux-server-getting-facebook-http-authentication-message). Please consider not opening a new question for every small detail of your project, if those minor details fit well into the context of an existing one. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever got this right? How??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is 80 equal 8080? Apparently no. So the both ports might be listened by different applications.
Try to inspect income requests with Wireshark (packet analyzer).

Comment: I got wireshark and checked out the packets being sent. It looks like it is only trying to request on port 8080. I'm not sure how I could fix this. Should I send a small html file that will redirect the client back to port 80 so that Apache can resume sending down the necessary information?

Comment: If your browser connects to port 8080 by default it is really strange. It must connect to port 80 firstly and only after that it may try another port if some kind of redirection exists. Filter packets by 'tcp.port == 80 || tcp.port == 8080' and inspect requests carefully. If there aren't requests to port 80, describe how you try to connect in detail.